# Why do I get a 401.1 response for a website with Anonymous access enabled?

Tags: iis, iis-6, windows-2003-webserver

I have a Windows 2003 web server that is serving up 3 public-facing websites via IIS6. The all run under the Default App Pool.

I have added a new, very simple, one page website to serve as a "Maintenance" website. It is setup with anonymous access enabled, and all 404 errors redirect to /index.html.

I basically stop the other 3 websites and start the Maintenance website when it is needed.

The other three websites function normally all day long.

However, the Maintenance website presents users with a login credentials dialog and/or responds with a 401.1 code. I tried adding the IIS_USR account to the directory security with Read and Read & Execute access, but I still have the same result.

I have a very similar setup on three other servers, which serve up additional public-facing websites.

What is going on and how can I fix this?

Comment: I had came across similar issue long back in 2008. That time issue was IIS_USR account password was out of sync. adsutil.vbs helps you to sync password. Basically you need to reset IIS_USR account password and sync it. You can confirm if you are facing same issue by swapping  IIS_USR with some other account. Once confirmed you can go ahead  and follow syncing procedure. Here is link for steps to sync password. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/332167   First reset it then sync it.  As a precaution please first test it on your backup server and then try it on production servers.

Comment: Use this link to check IUSR password http://windowsitpro.com/windows/how-can-i-check-password-iusr-and-iwam-local-accounts-machine

Comment: @PankajKapare This worked (I followed the steps in the third option). Please enter is as an answer and I will mark it as such. Thank you.